# Анимация вертикального появления background

Tags: css3, html5, css-animation

Необходимо изменить цвет background, есть блок с вложенными элементами у этого блока белый background при загрузке страницы, через 4 секунды сверху появляется  background другого цвета, элементы должны оставаться на странице с момента загрузки.
 Я написал код для демонстрации появления фона, убрав блок отрицательным margin, но этот вариант для меня недопустим, т.к. вложенные элементы скрываются с блоком. 
Какие есть варианты решения ?
 

Заранее спасибо.

```css
body,header,ul,section,h2{
   margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
header ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background:grey;
 
}
section{
  height:100vh;
  background: #20495B;
  animation: backgroundColor 3s linear;
  margin-top: 0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes backgroundColor{
    0% { 
        margin-top: -800px
    }
    100% {  
        margin-top: 0;
     }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">item1</a></li>
    <li><a href=""></a>item1</li>
    <li><a href=""></a>item1</li>
    <li><a href=""></a>item1</li>
  </ul></header>
  <main>
    <section>
      <h2>hellow</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, reiciendis, expedita. Ducimus ex nostrum quidem dolore facilis cum expedita, fugiat consectetur error numquam necessitatibus libero sint consequatur. Ea, facere! Facilis.</p>
      <h3>Lorem</h3>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По вашему вопросу очень трудно понять что вы хотите, я не знаю насколько правильно я сделал ответ на основании вашего вопроса, но если дадите подробное описание что вы хотите на выходе, переделаю.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
header ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: grey;
}

main section {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
main section:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #20495B;
  transform: translateY(0);
  animation: background-top-transform 3s ease;
}
main .container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes background-top-transform {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
  <header>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">item1</a></li>
    <li><a href=""></a>item1</li>
    <li><a href=""></a>item1</li>
    <li><a href=""></a>item1</li>
  </ul></header>
  <main>
    <section>
      <div class="container">
   <h2>hellow</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, reiciendis, expedita. Ducimus ex nostrum quidem dolore facilis cum expedita, fugiat consectetur error numquam necessitatibus libero sint consequatur. Ea, facere! Facilis.</p>
      <h3>Lorem</h3>
   </div>
    </section>
  </main>
```

Сниппет с SASS: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/molof/pen/VwwQZqm)

Comment: Именно то что мне было нужно, спасибо @MoloF